# Stop an input field in a form from being submitted in react-hook-form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

I was doing form validation in **react** with **react-hook-form** npm package. It has field like First Name, Last Name, Email, Password and Confirm Password. When I click on submit it will be handled by **handleSubmit** from **useForm()** hook. But I don't want to include Confirm Password filed value in the data that I got after submitting the form.

Here I have shared the code that I have written ...

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
 <TextField
   required
   fullWidth
   name="password"
   label="Password"
   type="password"
   id="password"
   autoComplete="new-password"
   {...register("password", { required: "Required"})}
   error={!!errors.password}
   helperText={errors?.password ? errors.password.message : null}
/>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <TextField
    required
    fullWidth
    name="confirmPassword"
    label="Confirm Password"
    type="password"
    id="confirmPassword"
    {...register("confirmPassword", { 
      required: "Required",
      validate: (val) => {
      if(watch('password') != val) {
         return "Password does not match"
      }
    }
    })}
    error={!!errors.confirmPassword}
    helperText={errors?.confirmPassword ? errors.confirmPassword.message : null}
 />
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove those fields in handleSubmit callback:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
        delete data.confirmPassword;
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      };
```

working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-handlesubmit-v7-uqmiy?file=/src/index.jsx:195-230
another option to use unregister:

```
<div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" {...unregister("password")} placeholder="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I found the second one for better code structure and easy to use ... Thanks sharing